# Query column of arrays with array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql

I have a database column with the datatype array. How can I query an array with an array in rails? For example, I have an array of software for an OS in my Product table  and I want to query them like this:

```
selected_products = ['Apple', 'Linux']

Software.where("'#{selected_products}' = ANY (osses)")
```

edit:

example of Software table:

```
id  |  software    |        osses         |
_______________________________________________________

1     product 1     {'Windows', 'Apple', 'Android'}
2     product 2     {'Android', 'Linux'}
3     product 3     {'Windows,', 'Android'}
4     product 4     {'Windows'}
```

In which case I'd like the query to return id's 1 and 2 (since id 1 has a match in Apple and id 2 has a match in Linux.)

Comment: Can you give us a concrete example (eg what the data would look like in the table and what you'd pass to it and what the result would like like - if you were god and could make it however you like? :)

Comment: updated, is it any clearer now?

Comment: So you'd like to "return a uniquified array of software_for_products from the rows that have one of the given OSs"?

Comment: Actually I'd like for it to return a relation for each match for further processing.

Comment: ok... so now I'm unclear what you're selecting on. Are you just wanting to find all products that have an OS from the set you give? How does the software_for_products part come in?

Comment: sorry, I mucked my example up completely in the first edit. I fixed it now to better correspond what I'm looking for.

Comment: right - that makes more sense... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Please look into this gem.](https://github.com/dockyard/postgres_ext/blob/master/docs/querying.md)

And then do a query like

```
selected_products = ['Apple', 'Linux']
Software.where.overlap(osses: selected_products)
```